# PHP Variable returns blank in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a module in my website where i am trying to implement a count down feature in based on date. I have tried following but the php varibale is returning blank in when i alert it in javascript. Also some times Nan. Below is the code. I need same value to be printed as it gets when i echo from PHP

```
<html>
    <head> 
    <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
   alert(<?php echo $newDate?>);
   </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
    $originalDate = "2018-08-31";
      echo $newDate = date("F j, Y",strtotime($originalDate));
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're attempting to use a variable before it exists. If you turn on error reporting PHP would have warned you about this. Just move the PHP code to the top of the page.

Comment: Any solution to this as how i can get the date in javascript ?

Comment: Thanks Buddy it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2018-08-31";
  newDate = date("F j, Y",strtotime($originalDate));?>
<html>
<head> 
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
alert(<?php echo $newDate?>);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo newDate;?>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: This will work because you first define variable and then output it. PHP loads first. So, in this case variable newDate is defined and then already defined variable is used in alert and in body.

Comment: Yes, but [why](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535)?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to echo the script via php. just as below,

```
<html>
  <head> 
  <script>
    <?php
    $originalDate = "2018-08-35";
    $newDate = date("F j, Y",strtotime($originalDate));

    echo "alert('$newDate')";
    ?>
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $newDate?>
  </body>
</html>
```